# org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response:

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, resttemplate

I'm creating a restful API which will consume json from server. But i'm getting the foll exception :

> org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [[Lexamples.dto.DummyDTO;] and content type [text/json;charset=utf-8]
>           at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:84)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:454)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:409)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:207)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:189)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)

Code snippet :

```
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> msgConverters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
msgConverters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(msgConverters);
DummyDTO[] dummy= restTemplate.getForObject(URI, DummyDTO[].class);
```

Controller method code :

```
public UserDTO[] getUserList(){
             List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
           acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        // Set the Accept and Content type header
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
           headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
            HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(headers);

            // Add the Jackson message converter
            List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> msgConverters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
            msgConverters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
            restTemplate.setMessageConverters(msgConverters);

            // Make the HTTP GET request, marshalling the response from JSON to an array of Users
            ResponseEntity<UserDTO[]> responseEntity  =   restTemplate.exchange("http://server.com",HttpMethod.GET, entity, UserDTO[].class);
            return responseEntity.getBody();
        }
```

Please tell me where am i going wrong

Comment: try return type as application/json instead of text/json and do provide controller code.

Comment: @rishman  To change the content type to application/json, i made changes to existing method. Still getting the same error . I've edited my post to include controller code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you change content type for request, but "application/json" have to be in the response headers, and the fact that you still have the same exception tells that you have wrong media type "text/json" in the response, there are no such [media type in HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type). Just look at implementation of `restTemplate.exchange("http://server.com",HttpMethod.GET, entity, UserDTO[].class);` there the problem should be.

Comment: yes the problem was the response type. once i changed it to application/json, things worked! Thanks!